# Passing table name to a variable to use it for destination file name in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, filenames

My requirement is that I need to spool multiple tables in SQL Server to as many CSVs using SSIS.
The filename convention should be somethin like below:

```
TABLENAME_MAX(Period)_GETDATE().csv
```

I can get the getdate() and Max(Period), that is fine.
How do I store the table name to a variable so that I can use it as an expression for the CSV connection manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the list of tables in another table. Then use loop container in SSIS to loop.

Ex: http://pldineshtech.blogspot.in/2012/08/loop-through-each-row-in-table-using.html

Comment: Any other method? I don't think the above method is going to help me out.
Or if you can explain me in more detail.

Comment: It is well explained in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your help... althought the above link did not help me completely... But I did get a vague idea from it I managed to solve my issue. Acceoting your answer... :)